# e4 pure rcp application: bring the currently running e4 app on front on second start tentative?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-luna

In a "pure e4" rcp application (v4.5.2), when the user tries to start for a second time the application, it fails with a popup:
"Could not launch the product because the associated workspace is currently in use by another Eclipse application"
Is there a way to set the focus on the current running app and bring it to the front of the desktop instead of failing with this error in a popup?
The check is done by some core code in eclipse before any callback app annotated method are called (eg method annotated with  @PostContextCreate), which make a lot of sense..

Answer (score 0):

The `eclipse{.exe}` launcher has support for this, but only in a limited use case. Opening files in running instance.

You could update/modify `eclipse.exe` to add such support. The source code that tries to reuse the Eclipse is in git. The relevant point is right [near the beginning of `main()`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/features/org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature/library/eclipse.c#n524):

```c
    /* try to open the specified file in an already running eclipse */
    /* on Mac we are only registering an event handler here, always do this */
#ifndef MACOSX
    if (filePath != NULL && filePath[0] != NULL)
#endif
    {
            int timeout = 60;
            if (timeoutString != NULL)
                    _stscanf(timeoutString, _T_ECLIPSE("%d"), &timeout);
            if (reuseWorkbench(filePath, timeout) > 0)
                    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonah for the comment but this way is way too complex for me to change and recompile eclipse.exe. I was more expecting a "java" solution